# Is there some shell full path function?

Tags: shell, pathname

Is there some native function(shell, linux command) to merge/compute the full path?

example:

```
old_path="~/test1/test2/../dir3//file.txt"
new_path=FUN($old_path)

echo "$new_path"   // I want get this "/home/user/test1/dir3/file.txt"
```

Comment: `realpath -m $(eval echo "$old_path")` may or may not help you. Note that `eval` is a security risk, use it responsibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `readlink`:

```
$ readlink -m ~/foo.txt
/home/user/foo.txt
$ readlink -m ~/somedir/..foo.txt
/home/user/foo.txt
```

It also handles symlinks.

Comment: This doesn't work if the pathname is in a variable.

Comment: @Jens: You're probably referring to tilde expansion in a variable.  In that event, it'd make sense to use `${HOME}` instead as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
  new_path=$(eval cd "$old_path"; pwd)
```

work for you? You can also use `pwd -P` if you want symlinks resolved. You can make life easier if you use `$HOME` instead of `~` in `old_path`. Then you don't need the `eval`.

Comment: Or use `pwd -P`. Then `eval` is unnecessary.

Comment: @glglgl The eval is always needed to perform tilde expansion.

Comment: Luckily, my `bash` hasn't read this comment so it doesn't know about. If I enter `echo $(cd ~/mp3; pwd -P)`, I get `/home/glglgl/mp3`. If I'd put it into a variable instead, the same would happen.

Comment: does it change current working path？

Comment: @glglgl No it doesn't. You're running a different command and I suggest you actually *do* put it in a variable with quotes. If `foo="~"; cd $foo` works in your bash, it is broken. The problem is that tilde expansion occurs *before* parameter expansion when using `$foo`.

Comment: @YifanWang No it doesn't change the current working dir because the `cd` is run in a subshell.